# Complex SP for monthly sales returning wrong data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, reporting

I will try to explain this problem, and i simplified the two needed tables that is important in this procedure:

```
**Table 1: book_sales**
identifiers
sales_price
sales_date
store
quantity

**Table2: discount**
identifiers
sales_price (the changed / discounted price)
from_date
to_date
```

- If the `to_date` in `Discount` table is '2999-01-01' it should overwrite the `sales price` in `book_sales` (In this example it is: 99,-)
- If the `from_date` and `to_date` in `Discount` table is for just a period, lets say From_Date: 2014-02-03 and To_Date 2014-02-05 it should overwrite the other prices for exactly that period. (In this example it is 69,-)

My stored procedure is supposed to return data like this:

```
+------------+-----------+---------+----+-----+
| 2014-02-01 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  3 |  99 |
| 2014-02-02 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  99 |
| 2014-02-03 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  69 |
| 2014-02-04 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  69 |
| 2014-02-05 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  69 |
| 2014-02-06 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  99 |
+------------+-----------+---------+----+-----+
```

But it is showing both and returning data like this:

```
+------------+-----------+---------+----+-----+
| 2014-02-01 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  3 |  99 |
| 2014-02-01 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  3 |  69 |
| 2014-02-02 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  99 |
| 2014-02-02 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  69 |
| 2014-02-03 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  99 |
| 2014-02-03 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  69 |
+------------+-----------+---------+----+-----+
```

etc...
So this is the actual procedure, can you guys see anything wrong?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Loid] @month         INT, 
                             @year          INT, 
                             @report_source NVARCHAR(255), 
                             @is_primary    INT 
AS 
    SELECT Cast(isa.sales_date AS DATE)                                   AS 
           DATE, 
           BV.name, 
           isa.identifiers, 
           isa.quantity, 
           Isnull(id.sales_price, Isnull(u.sales_price, isa.sales_price)) AS 
           SALES_PRICE 
    FROM   book_sales AS isa 
           INNER JOIN store AS BV 
                   ON bv.store_id = isa.store_id 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN discount AS id 
                        ON id.identifiers = isa.identifiers 
                           AND id.from_date <= isa.sales_date 
                           AND id.to_date >= isa.sales_date 
                           AND id.to_date < '2999-01-01' 
                           AND BV.name = id.store 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN discount AS u 
                        ON u.identifiers = isa.identifiers 
                           AND u.to_date = '2999-01-01' 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN book_contributor AS BC 
                        ON BC.book_id = isa.book_id 
    WHERE  Month(isa.sales_date) = @month 
           AND Year(isa.sales_date) = @year 
           AND isa.report_source = @report_source 
           AND bc.is_primary = @is_primary
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide sample data for source tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the result i assume you have set a from_date value to discount records which has to_date  '2999-01-01'

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN discount AS id 
ON id.identifiers = isa.identifiers 
AND id.from_date <= isa.sales_date 
AND id.to_date >= isa.sales_date
```

If so in this join statement those discount records also joins which creates duplicate records.

Either you can set from_date to a higher value like '2999-01-01' for the discount records which has to_date '2999-01-01' or change the join statemnt as below.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN discount AS id 
ON id.identifiers = isa.identifiers 
AND id.from_date <= isa.sales_date 
AND id.to_date >= isa.sales_date 
AND id.to_date < '2999-01-01'
```

**EDIT**

According to chat following should work. A new condition **BV.name = u.store** is added to second join with discount table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Loid] @month         INT, 
                             @year          INT, 
                             @report_source NVARCHAR(255), 
                             @is_primary    INT 
AS 
    SELECT Cast(isa.sales_date AS DATE)                                   AS 
           DATE, 
           BV.name, 
           isa.identifiers, 
           isa.quantity, 
           Isnull(id.sales_price, Isnull(u.sales_price, isa.sales_price)) AS 
           SALES_PRICE 
    FROM   book_sales AS isa 
           INNER JOIN store AS BV 
                   ON bv.store_id = isa.store_id 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN discount AS id 
                        ON id.identifiers = isa.identifiers 
                           AND id.from_date <= isa.sales_date 
                           AND id.to_date >= isa.sales_date 
                           AND id.to_date < '2999-01-01' 
                           AND BV.name = id.store 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN discount AS u 
                        ON u.identifiers = isa.identifiers 
                           AND u.to_date = '2999-01-01'
                           AND BV.name = u.store  
           LEFT OUTER JOIN book_contributor AS BC 
                        ON BC.book_id = isa.book_id 
    WHERE  Month(isa.sales_date) = @month 
           AND Year(isa.sales_date) = @year 
           AND isa.report_source = @report_source 
           AND bc.is_primary = @is_primary
```

Comment: Wow that actually worked out !!!!!
Only problem now is that its not taking store into consideration. It is now printing the prices for all stores and not the ones specified to have special prices..

Comment: Is store table contains store details which specified to have special prices? Then join with store table should be a inner join

Comment: I updated the procedure now, can you see whats wrong? i tried inner join, and added: AND BV.name = id.store

Comment: Is there a table which contains data about the stores which are providing special prices? It seems like store table hold all the store records.

Comment: All prices are stored in book_sales and discount. Store only consists of the store name and store id. so i had to join because the store name has to be the same as in discount.

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand that edit. I have to make a new column in store? 

I thought that  storename=storename, identifiers=identifiers, and from_date=from_date would be enough? and also, all stores can have special prices.. so then all of them would have True?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49390/discussion-between-dcp1986-and-lebowski)